# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets

Tags: python, keras, nlp, evaluation

I am trying to predict a model using Independent variable (Arabic Sentence) and Dependent variables (Multiclass but using One Hot encoding technique. I used Tokenizer Technique for Train and test set

The Model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(num_words,32,input_length=max_length))
model.add(LSTM(64,dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(4,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# some code here

model.fit(train_padded,y_train,epochs=1, validation_data=(test_padded,y_test))
```

The problem is when I use score = `f1_score(y_test, ynew, average='weighted')` as evaluation. It shows the following error:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets
```

*ynew* and *y_test* values are the following:

```
ynew= array([2, 1, 3, ..., 3, 0, 1]`, dtype=int64)

y_test = array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: When I use ynew = model.predict_classes(test_padded) the result become array([2, 1, 3, ..., 3, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
which means that it convert my binary classes to decimal

Comment: So what is the problem? predict_classes does exactly that, you might want to use predict instead.

Comment: There is no "below error", please add details to your question (you can edit it), not as comments

Comment: added in the question @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both arguments of *f1_score()* must be in the same format: either one-hot encoding or label encoding. You cannot pass two differently encoded arguments. Use one of the following options.

**Option 1**: You could convert *ynew* to one-hot encoding.

```
# one-hot encode ynew, before calculating f1_score
ynew = keras.utils.to_categorical(ynew)
f1_score(y_test, ynew, average='weighted')
```

**Option 2**: You could convert *y_new* to one-hot encoding using LabelBinarizer.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
# one-hot encode ynew, before calculating f1_score
ynew = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(ynew)
f1_score(y_test, ynew, average='weighted')
```

**Option 3**: You could convert *y_test* from one-hot encoding to label encoding.

```
import numpy as np
# label encode y_test, before calculating f1_score
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
f1_score(y_test, ynew, average='weighted')
```